# URL to Library Search Query

Tags: document-library, search, url

Is it possible to link to a Document Library with a search query executed (in a similar way to linking to a filtered library).

I carry out a specific search and display results in the library regularly and would prefer to have a shortcut to this, but looking at the URL the query doesn't seem to be shown, it just adds a "#InplviewHash" parameter with a hex value, i.e. not readable!

Comment: +1 Did you find a solution? I just found out about the filtered library.. so if you found a solution, let me know! :)